# Regex to match and return group names

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match the following strings and returns the values as groups:

```
abctic
abctac
xyztic
xyztac
ghhtic
ghhtac
```

Pattern is wrote with grouping is as follows:

```
(?<arch>[abc,xyz,ghh])(?<flavor>[tic,tac]$)
```

The above returns only parts of group names. (meaning match is not correct).

If I use `*` in each sub pattern instead of `$` at the end, groups are correct, but that would mean that abcticff will also match.

Please let me know what my correct regex should be.

Comment: Here is my pattern. (?<arch>[abc,xyz,ghh])(?<flavor>[tic,tac]$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect because a pipe symbol `|` is used to specify alternate matches, not a comma in brackets as you were using, i.e., `[x,y]`.

Your pattern should be: `^(?<arch>abc|xyz|ghh)(?<flavor>tic|tac)$`
The `^` and `$` metacharacters ensures the string matches from start to end. If you need to match text in a larger string you could replace them with `\b` to match on a word boundary.

Try this approach:

```
string[] inputs = { "abctic", "abctac", "xyztic", "xyztac", "ghhtic", "ghhtac" };
string pattern = @"^(?<arch>abc|xyz|ghh)(?<flavor>tic|tac)$";

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arch: {0} - Flavor: {1}",
                            match.Groups["arch"].Value,
                            match.Groups["flavor"].Value);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No match for: " + input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ahmad! I didnt realize I was using ,. Thanks again.